# Different Ways To Normalize a Dataset

Tags: normalization

So I have read up on normalizing using the minmax scaler aka x-xmin/(xmax-xmin) and standardizing data using the Z-score method. I came across 2 people doing normalization a different way (https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-variance-thresholding-for-robust-feature-selection-a4503f2b5c3f). TLDR:
normalized_df = ansur_male_num / ansur_male_num.mean()
They divided each column of the data set by their respective means. Is this common? What are the pros and cons compared to the min-max version? Is dividing by the mean more preferable when using Variance Threshold? If anyone can link me to a scholarly paper that explains this it is much appreciated.